# Change button link dynamically when specific radios from 2 different groups are selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm trying to write this:

```
when radio button 2 from Group 1 AND radio button 2 from Group 2 are selected
    replace Continue button with special link, dynamically while still on page
else
    keep/rewrite with this standard link, also on page
```

So that no matter what combo from two groups is selected...

```
GROUP 1
Radio1 / Radio2

GROUP 2
Radio1 / Radio 2
```

If Radio 2 + Radio 2 are selected, the link in the Continue button will auto change, and when any other combo is selected, it will immediately change back to the default link.

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function() {
         if ($('#select_btn_forSelect2').is(':checked') && $('#select_btn_forSelectOther2').is(':checked')) {
             alert("Both are currently checked");
             $('.continue-button').replaceWith('<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="/link1">' + "Continue" +'</a>');
         } else {
             alert("Only one, or neither of these was clicked");
             $('.continue-button').replaceWith('<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="/link2">' + "Continue" +'</a>');
         }
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: because you should get the checked status on change not on load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {// catch the check status on radio button change.
      if ($('#select_btn_forSelect2').is(':checked') && $('#select_btn_forSelectOther2').is(':checked')) {
        alert("Both are currently checked");
      } else {
        alert("Only one, or neither of these was clicked");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='group1' id='select_btn_forSelect' />
<input type='radio' name='group1' id='select_btn_forSelect2' class='checked' />
<br>
<input type='radio' name='group2' id='select_btn_forSelectOther' />
<input type='radio' name='group2' id='select_btn_forSelectOther2' class='checked' />


<input type='button' value='button' name='group2' class='continue-button' />
```

Check this out

Comment: glad to help happy coding mate